# How can I suppress the overwrite dialog for a content file in a nuget package I created?

Tags: nuget

In NuGet 2.5, a dialog was added to prompt the user if they want to overwrite content files that are included in a nuget package if they already exist.

I would like to suppress this dialog and make it so that the file would never be overwritten.

The reason is that my package adds a file into the App_Start folder, and the user must place custom configuration code in this file.  When the package is updated, the user is prompted if they want to overwrite the file with the blank one from the nuget package.  If someone accidentally clicked Yes, they might loose important code.

Is it possible to configure the package in some way so that it will never prompt the user to overwrite this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a PowerShell script instead. This would allow you to take full control over whether the file was created or not.

The only thing that NuGet provides is an FileConflictAction argument you can pass to the PowerShell console when installing the NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks. I will switch to using a powershell script.

Comment: Any new updates on this request? Is it possible to achieve this in a different way by either using nuspec?